# Sqlalchemy query returns incorrect and outdated results (for sqlite engine)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using sqlalchemy with sqlite engine (development server) and just discovered that after update query, queries in next web-requests return outdated data set (that depends on fact which thread is used for the request, as I understand there is a pool of threads).

I'm using `scoped_session` and the other recommended stuff from docs (`DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))`).

Here is the example of web requests and what's executed there.

```
request-1:thread-1: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 -> (id:1, data:1)
request-2:thread-2: UPDATE table SET data=2 WHERE id=1; COMMIT
request-3:thread-1: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 -> (id:1, data:1) // STILL data:1 !
request-4:thread-4: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 -> (id:1, data:2) // NEW DATA!     
request-5:thread-1: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 -> (id:1, data:1) // AND AGAIN OLD DATA!
```

What is this? How can I avoid this behaviour? In the example above all web requests are executed in consecutive order, so SQL-queries do not intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the `pyramid_tm` tween.

```
[app:main]

pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_tm
```

The tween commits transactions after each request, implicitly starting a *new* transaction when a new request comes in.

When you do not start a new transaction, the *old* transaction will not see data committed in other transactions (threads); this is a inherent feature of database transactions, as not doing so would lead to inconsistency errors.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but it looks a bit overfeatured to me. Basically I do need to start transaction on each request, but don't need to automatically commit/abort it upon request finish.

Comment: Starting a transaction *requires* you to end the previous one first. When no writes have taken place transaction commits are cheap anyway.

Comment: Ok, just added added `pyramid_tm`, enabled `tm.commit_veto` but I don't see any `ROLLBACK` or `ABORT` messages in the log if I send `4xx` status. Is it OK? Btw, manual `transaction.abort()` call doesn't call `ROLLBACK` either.

Comment: `transaction` actions are not SQL commands; there is no `connection.execute('ABORT')` or `connection.execute('ROLLBACK') being executed; it's a connection-level method.

Comment: I understand that and if I manually do `dbsession.rollback()` I see corresponding message (`ROLLBACK`). So how can I be sure that `transaction.abort()` is really working? Of cource I can enable txn. logger and see somethin like `2013-09-09 17:38:52,334 DEBUG [txn.140227417442048][Dummy-2] abort` but why there is no any related messages from db engine?

Comment: @SergeyStolyarov: That's because SQLAlchemy's session does issue a log message when you use that method; the `zope.sqlalchemy` transaction manager works with distributed transactions (supporting more than one database) and uses a lower-level transaction API of the session to achieve it's functionality and that doesn't emit a log message. You should always use the `transaction` package (`import transaction; transaction.abort()` for example) to manage your transactions when using `pyramid_tm`.

Answer (score 1):

You could issue a [`Session.refresh`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.refresh) with the database object you want to get the value of.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, but it gave me a hint, maybe sqlalchemy thinks the connection in that thread is in the transaction state.

Comment: I've got an advice to perform `transaction.commit()` after getting dbsession instance at the beginning of web request handler, always. It was helpful in my case, but I still don't understand exactly how sqlalchemy (or probably sqlite) deals with the transactions.

Comment: @SergeyStolyarov well I usually do that myself before starting any process that could end-up making changes to the database.

Comment: In my case if I don't do that before SELECT I'll get outdated data. Looks weird to me, there is something wrong with the transactions there.