# About refreshing objects in sqlalchemy session

Tags: python, mysql, session, notifications, sqlalchemy

I am dealing with a doubt about sqlalchemy and objects refreshing!

I am in the situation in what I have 2 sessions, and the same object has been queried in both sessions! For some particular thing I cannot to close one of the sessions.
I have modified the object and commited the changes in session A, but in session B, the attributes are the initial ones! without modifications!

Shall I implement a notification system to communicate changes or there is a built-in way to do this in sqlalchemy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18684124/1309352

Comment: This can help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25694346/134904

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[Sessions are designed to work like this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do). The attributes of the object in Session B WILL keep what it had when first queried in Session B. Additionally, SQLAlchemy will not attempt to automatically refresh objects in other sessions when they change, nor do I think it would be wise to try to create something like this.

You should be actively thinking of the lifespan of each session as a single transaction in the database. How and when sessions need to deal with the fact that their objects might be stale is not a technical problem that can be solved by an algorithm built into SQLAlchemy (or any extension for SQLAlchemy): it is a "business" problem whose solution you must determine and code yourself. The "correct" response might be to say that this isn't a problem: the logic that occurs with Session B could be valid if it used the data at the time that Session B started. Your "problem" might not actually be a problem. The docs actually have an [entire section on when to use sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it), but it gives a pretty grim response if you are hoping for a one-size-fits-all solution...

> A Session is typically constructed at the beginning of a logical
>   operation where database access is potentially anticipated.
>
> The Session, whenever it is used to talk to the database, begins a
>   database transaction as soon as it starts communicating. Assuming the
>   autocommit flag is left at its recommended default of False, this
>   transaction remains in progress until the Session is rolled back,
>   committed, or closed. The Session will begin a new transaction if it
>   is used again, subsequent to the previous transaction ending; from
>   this it follows that the Session is capable of having a lifespan
>   across many transactions, though only one at a time. We refer to these
>   two concepts as transaction scope and session scope.
>
> The implication here is that the SQLAlchemy ORM is encouraging the
>   developer to establish these two scopes in his or her application,
>   including not only when the scopes begin and end, but also the expanse
>   of those scopes, for example should a single Session instance be local
>   to the execution flow within a function or method, should it be a
>   global object used by the entire application, or somewhere in between
>   these two.
>
> The burden placed on the developer to determine this scope is one area
>   where the SQLAlchemy ORM necessarily has a strong opinion about how
>   the database should be used. The unit of work pattern is specifically
>   one of accumulating changes over time and flushing them periodically,
>   keeping in-memory state in sync with what’s known to be present in a
>   local transaction. This pattern is only effective when meaningful
>   transaction scopes are in place.

That said, there are a few things you can do to change how the situation works:

First, you can reduce how long your session stays open. Session B is querying the object, then later you are doing something with that object (in the same session) that you want to have the attributes be up to date. One solution is to have this second operation done in a separate session.

Another is to use the expire/refresh methods, as the [docs show](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring)...

```
# immediately re-load attributes on obj1, obj2
session.refresh(obj1)
session.refresh(obj2)

# expire objects obj1, obj2, attributes will be reloaded
# on the next access:
session.expire(obj1)
session.expire(obj2)
```

You can use `session.refresh()` to immediately get an up-to-date version of the object, even if the session already queried the object earlier.

Comment: Thx! I wanna say that i have read the complete Sessions Documentation. But, even having done that, i have some problems dettecting where to start the session and where to end it up in my application code, and that is not in the documentation haha.

Comment: When and how to use sessions is going to be different from application to application. There is no one size fits all solution, and describing how one would go about the process of determining that could be an entire book itself. So, don't feel bad that you're unsure of how to do it, since it's not a simple problem.

Comment: well, saying this, i feel more free about creating a workflow that satisfy my needs, and don't trying to find a pattern where it cannot exists!

Comment: Additionally, to the solution provided, you could try to use `Session.merge`.

Comment: All the link are dead now.

Comment: @ShiheZhang Updated links.

Comment: Appreciated the in-depth answer. I was just looking for session.refresh(obj1) but the context was super helpful.

Answer (score 20):

Run this, to force session to update latest value from your database of choice:

```
session.expire_all()
```

[Excellent DOC about default behavior and lifespan of session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#refreshing-expiring)

Answer (score 16):

I just had this issue and the existing solutions didn't work for me for some reason.  What did work was to call `session.commit()`.  After calling that, the object had the updated values from the database.

Comment: Same for me. I think expire/refresh work on ORM level not on transaction level. This makes expire/refresh ineffective in cases where other transaction commits. One has to commit/rollback in order to see new data.

Comment: Excellent, simple solution! As other have pointed out `session.expire_all()` doesn't work in case of a separate session.

Comment: Samething for my case

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR Rather than working on Session synchronization, see if your task can be reasonably easily coded with SQLAlchemy Core syntax, directly on the Engine, without the use of (multiple) Sessions

For someone coming from SQL and JDBC experience, one critical thing to learn about SQLAlchemy, which, unfortunately, I didn't clearly come across reading through the multiple documents for months is that SQLAlchemy consists of two fundamentally different parts: the Core and the ORM. As the ORM documentation is listed first on the website and most examples use the ORM-like syntax, one gets thrown into working with it and sets them-self up for errors and confusion - if thinking about ORM in terms of SQL/JDBC. ORM uses its own abstraction layer that takes a complete control over how and when actual SQL statements are executed. The rule of thumb is that a Session is cheap to create and kill, and it should never be re-used for anything in the program's flow and logic that may cause re-querying, synchronization or multi-threading. On the other hand, the Core is the direct no-thrills SQL, very much like a JDBC Driver. There is one place in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_events.html#mapper-level-events) I found that "suggests" using Core over ORM:

> it is encouraged that simple SQL operations take place here, directly on the Connection, such as incrementing counters or inserting extra rows within log 
>   tables. When dealing with the Connection, it is expected that Core-level SQL 
>   operations will be used; e.g. those described in SQL Expression Language Tutorial.

Although, it appears that using a Connection causes the same side effect as using a Session: re-query of a specific record returns the same result as the first query, even if the record's content in the DB was changed. So, apparently Connections are as "unreliable" as Sessions to read DB content in "real time", but a direct Engine execution seems to be working fine as it picks a Connection object from the pool (assuming that the retrieved Connection would never be in the same "reuse" state relatively to the query as the specific open Connection). The Result object should be closed explicitly, as per SA docs

Answer (score 1):

What is your isolation level is set to?

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'transaction_isolation';
```

By default mysql innodb `transaction_isolation` is set to `REPEATABLE-READ`.

```
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name         | Value           |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| transaction_isolation | REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

Consider setting it to `READ-COMMITTED`.

You can set this for your sqlalchemy engine only via:

```py
create_engine("mysql://<connection_string>", isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
```

I think another option is:

```py
engine = create_engine("mysql://<connection_string>")
engine.execution_options(isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
```

Or set it globally in the DB via:

```sql
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

and

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-dbapi-autocommit

Answer (score 0):

If u had added the incorrect model to the `session`, u can do:

```
db.session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for asyncio.For Asynchronous IO use `await engine.dispose()`  after operation.